# Optimizing looping through dataset

Tags: delphi, loops

I have a code some thing like this

```
dxMemOrdered : TdxMemData;
while not qrySandbox2.EOF do
    begin
      dxMemOrdered.append;
      dxMemOrderedTotal.asCurrency := qrySandbox2.FieldByName('TOTAL').asCurrency;
      dxMemOrdered.post;
      qrySandbox2.Next;
    end;
```

this code executes in a thread. When there are huge records say "400000" it is taking around 25 minutes to parse through it. Is there any way that i can reduce the size by optimizing the loop? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Based on the suggestions i made the following changes

```
dxMemOrdered : TdxMemData;
qrySandbox2.DisableControls;
while not qrySandbox2.Recordset.EOF do
    begin
      dxMemOrdered.append;
      dxMemOrderedTotal.asCurrency := Recordset.Fields['TOTAL'].Value;  
      dxMemOrdered.post;
      qrySandbox2.Next;
    end;
qrySandbox2.EnableControls;
```

and my output time have improved from 15 mins to 2 mins. Thank you guys

Comment: Use that `try..finally` block as @whosrdaddy has in his answer. And a forward cursor I've mentioned might help you to improve reading from the source dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas in order of performance gain vs work to do by you:

1) Check if the SQL dialect that you are using lets you use queries that directly SELECT from/INSERT to. This depends on the database you're using.

2) Make sure that if your datasets are not coupled to visual controls, that you call DisableControls/EnableControls around this loop

3) Does this code have to run in the main program thread? Maybe you can send if off to a separate thread while the user/program continues doing something else

4) When you have to deal with really large data, bulk insertion is the way to go. Many databases have options to bulk insert data from text files. Writing to a text file first and then bulk inserting is way faster than individual inserts. Again, this depends on your database type.

[Edit: I just see you inserting the info that it's TdxMemData, so some of these no longer apply. And you're already threading, missed that ;-). I leave this suggestions in for other readers with similar problems]

Comment: OP already uses a thread. So the only point that is still valid for this question is in my view point 2. But except point 2 you might suggest to use some sort of read only forward cursor (depending on DB). [+1]

Comment: Updated my question with the answer.

Comment: @Jeeva, do you also have controls linked through dxMemOrdered?

Comment: @jeeva, then you also have to follow my suggestion :)

Comment: @whosrdaddy well i guess yes :)

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing more code, the only suggestion I can make is make sure that any visual control that is using the memory table is disabled. Suppose you have a cxgrid called `Grid` that is linked to your dxMemOrdered memory table:

```
var    
  dxMemOrdered: TdxMemData;
...

Grid.BeginUpdate;
try
  while not qrySandbox2.EOF do
  begin
    dxMemOrdered.append;
    dxMemOrderedTotal.asCurrency := qrySandbox2.FieldByName('TOTAL').asCurrency;
    dxMemOrdered.Post;
    qrySandbox2.Next;
  end;
finally
  Grid.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: So this same rule apply for even parsing TdxMemData? or what should we do for it

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to let SQL do the work instead of iterating though a loop in Delphi. Try a query such as

```
insert into dxMemOrdered (total)
select total from qrySandbox2
```

Is 'total' the only field in dxMemOrdered? I hope that it's not the primary key otherwise you are likely to have collisions, meaning that rows will not be added.

Comment: this wont work since dxMemOrdered is a Tdxmemdata component (inmemory table)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a lot you could do to speed up your thread.

The first would be to look at the problem in a broader perspective:

- Am I fetching data from a cached / fast disk, possibly moved in memory?
- Am I doing the right thing, when aggregating totals by hand? SQL engines are expecially optimized to do those things, all you'd need to do is to define an additional logical field where to store the SQL aggregated result.

Another little optimization that may bring an improvement over large amounts of looping is to not use constructs like:

- Recordset.Fields['TOTAL'].Value
- Recordset.FieldByName('TOTAL').Value

but to add the fields with the fields editor and then directly accessing the right field. You'll save a whole loop through the fields collection, that otherwise is performed on every field, on every next record.